# check and display multiple values in for loop

Tags: php

I have for loop in which I have to check that the array that I am retriving should not empty. And if empty then don't display that field.

```
        $checkboxes = array();
    $text = array();
    $Enhanced = array();
    $Search = array();
    $Landing = array();
    $spotlights="";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
         $checkboxes[$i] = $_POST[$i];
         $text[$i] = $_POST[$i.'t'];
    }

    for ($p = 1; $p <= 20; $p++) {
         $checkboxes[$p] = $_POST[$p];
         $Enhanced[$p] = $_POST['Enhanced'.$p];
    }
    for ($q = 1; $q <= 20; $q++) {
         $checkboxes[$q] = $_POST[$q];
         $Search[$q] = $_POST['Search'.$q];
    }
    for ($r = 1; $r <= 20; $r++) {
         $checkboxes[$r] = $_POST[$r];
         $Landing[$r] = $_POST['Landing'.$r];
    }
 for ($j = 1; $j <= 20; $j++) {

            if($checkboxes[$j]!="")
                {   

                $spotlights=$spotlights."<strong>".$checkboxes[$j]."</strong><br>".$Enhanced[$j]."<br>".$Search[$j]."<br>".$Landing[$j]."<br>".$text[$j]."<br><br>";

                }

            }
       echo $spotlights;
```

In above code, `$Enhanced[$j]`, `$Search[$j]`, `$Landing[$j]` may or may not be empty as these are `checkboxes`. If any of them is empty i don't want to print that. In above case if any of three field empty then it display `<br/>` which i don't want.

If I check them one by one or combination of them then my code will be longer.
How do I check in smarter way? How should I write the line of `$spotlights=...` so that it will display only non empty variables(`$Enhanced[$j]`, `$Search[$j]`, `$Landing[$j]`)?

I have tried bolow which is not working.
**using functions:**

```
    for ($j = 1; $j <= 20; $j++) {

    if($checkboxes[$j]!="")
        {   

        $spotlights=$spotlights."<strong>".$checkboxes[$j]."</strong>".enhanced($j).search($j).landing($j)."<br>".$text[$j]."<br><br>";

        }


    }
    function enhanced($j) {

    if($Enhanced[$j]!="")
        {   
        return "<br/>".$Enhanced[$j];
        }
}
    function search($j) {

    if($Search[$j]!="")
        {   
        return "<br/>".$Search[$j];
        }
}
    function landing($j) {

    if($Landing[$j]!="")
        {   
        return "<br/>".$Landing[$j];
        }
}
```

above code not displaying values of `$Enhanced[$j], $Search[$j], $Landing[$j]`

**checking values independently**

```
for ($j = 1; $j <= 20; $j++) {

if($checkboxes[$j]!="")
    {   

    $spotlights .= $spotlights."<strong>".$checkboxes[$j]."</strong>";

    if($Enhanced[$j]!="")
    {   
       $spotlights .= "<br>".$Enhanced[$j];

    }
    if($Search[$j]!="")
    {   
       $spotlights .= "<br>".$Search[$j];

    }
    if($Landing[$j]!="")
    {   
       $spotlights .= "<br>".$Landing[$j];

    }

     $spotlights .= "<br>".$text[$j]."<br><br>";

}
```

values are getting repeated by using above code.

Comment: if they are always array use `if(empty($checkboxes[$j])) ...`

Comment: Create function to check values are empty or not.

Comment: where are these coming from? `$Enhanced[$j], $Search[$j], $Landing[$j`

Comment: Checking them individually is simple and will do no harm I think.

Comment: @b0s3 checking individually will create more combinations i guess.

Comment: What combinations? As far as I understand you just have to check they are set or not. In any case you have add a check for that.

Comment: @CodeGodie I retriving them in array and displaying them as above.

Comment: but what if `$checkboxes` has only 1 array, and the others have more than one.. they will never show.. how are they related? maybe show more of your code, so we can understand how they relate

Comment: @CodeGodie updated my question.

Comment: $Enhanced[$j], $Search[$j], $Landing[$j] may not be empty because they are `'Enhanced'.$p` where `$p = (0<=20)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think checking them individually will be a lot of trouble, as there are only three of them, but if you want to keep it one line, the line where you define $spotlights with this:

```
    $spotlights=$spotlights."<strong>".$checkboxes[$j]."</strong>"
.($Enhanced[$j] != "" ? "<br>".$Enhanced[$j] : "")
.($Search[$j] != "" ? "<br>".$Search[$j] : "")
.($Landing[$j] != "" ? "<br>".$Landing[$j] : "")
."<br>".$text[$j]."<br><br>";
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Lightwind: its easy with `? :` rather than if loops in for loop. its cool. I forgot that operator. I have modified the above line. thanks for the help.

Comment: @novice Glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_filter`.
Something like that:

```
$checkboxes = array_filter($checkboxes);
    foreach($checkboxes as $checkbox)
    {
        $j = array_search($checkbox, $checkboxes)
            $spotlights=$spotlights."<strong>".$checkboxes[$j]."</strong><br>".$Enhanced[$j]."<br>".$Search[$j]."<br>".$Landing[$j]."<br>".$text[$j]."<br><br>";
        echo $spotlights;
    }
```

`array_filter` will remove all `NULL`, `false` or `''` from array, but will keep the position, so if you have in `checkbox[3]` something different, in `checkboxes` after `array_filter` will be on position 3. doesn't matter if on position 2 was `NULL`.

Comment: dont you think that taking $Enhanced[$j] will be unavailiable after array_filter due to the different indexes in arrays ?

Comment: What i told, in `checkboxes` indexes will not be modified.